# Preventing tuple out of bounds with "if constexpr"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

The following code compiles fine with GCC and Clang but stopped working in the latest update to Visual Studio (/std:c++latest):

```
#include <tuple>

template<int pos, typename... T>
void check_tuple(T... types) {
    if constexpr (pos <= -1) {
        // nothing
    } else {
        using Type = typename std::tuple_element<pos, std::tuple<T...>>::type;
    }
}

int main() {
    check_tuple<0>(1.0, 1.0);
    check_tuple<-1>(1.0, 1.0);
}
```

In the latest version of Visual Studio (/std:c++latest), compilation fails with tuple index out of bounds (std::tuple_element<18446744073709551613,std::tuple<>>).

Is is possible to prevent tuple out of bounds with constexpr like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a VS bug (please report to Microsoft). The code should work as is.

---

Until then, you can resort to how we used to solve this problem: tag disptaching.

```
template<int pos, typename... T>
void check_tuple_impl(std::true_type, T... types) {
    // nothing
}

template<int pos, typename... T>
void check_tuple_impl(std::false_type, T... types) {
    using Type = typename std::tuple_element<pos, std::tuple<T...>>::type;
}

template<int pos, typename... T>
void check_tuple(T... types) {
    check_tuple_impl<pos>(std::integral_constant<bool, (pos <= -1)>{}, types...);
}
```